# Collapsing a Grid row with an Expander

Tags: wpf, data-binding, grid, row, expander

How can I databind an Expander and a gridrow where the expander is placed (Expander/Collapsed = Row/Collapsed and vice versa) so that the next row under the row to be collapsed will be higher?

What I need is to collapse a grid (Grid) row with an expander (Expander).

P.S.: The both rows are separated with a GridSplitter.

thx

Comment: For a similar problem I created a Behavior using the System.Windows.Interactivity library...

Answer (score 0):

A bit sparse on info there, but have you checked if RowDetails does the thing you want to do?

Check [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx#rowdetails)
for an example.